# symfony2 API authentication and routing

Tags: php, url-routing, symfony, firewall

I followed the instructions for creating a custom authentication provider: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

**app/config/security**:

```
firewalls:
    wsse_protection:
        pattern: ^/api/.*
        wsse: true
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

Now I have some Actions in the Controllers with routes. e.g:

ExampleController with listAction

**routing**:

```
example_list:
    pattern: /example/list
    defaults: { ... }
```

Do I have to copy all the routes to example_api_list? Because api/example/list didnt work (no route found for /api/example/list). I thought the pattern from the firewall is a prefix for all defined routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firewall isn't a prefix, it's a regular expression that matches against incoming routes. In this case, anything starting with `/api` will be matched by your `wsse_protection` firewall, and everything that falls through will be matched by your `main` firewall.

To create routes under /api/*, you'll have to define the routing separately.

Comment: ok. thanks. In the meantime I got some problems in securing the controller methods. adding a @Secure(roles="ROLE_ADMIN") annotation will leading to a replay attac. Do you know how to solve that or what is the reason for?

Comment: The same with $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') or access_control to ROLE_ADMIN in security.yml.